# Angularjs routing without templates/my.html

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

ok, the basic routing is like this

```
sampleApp .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/addOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/add-order.html',
        controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
```

Now in my case, in the node.js server side, when `“/addOrder"`, it'll send text message back to web client.
So how should i set up the Angularjs routing please ?

Thanks !

Comment: you dont need routing for that.. you use should $http for that

Comment: ok, found some samples, let me try 1st. If you have good simple samples, i'd appreciate that too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `template: ' '` instead of `templateUrl:'templates/add-order.html'` .

```
sampleApp .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/addOrder', {
        template: ' ',
        controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
```